# let $f(n)$ denote the number of all possible values of $m$ such that $m = a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}...a_{n}$ for which $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3}...,a_{n}$ are digits

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

let $f(n)$ denote the number of all possible values of $m$ such that $m = a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}...a_{n}$ for which $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3}...,a_{n}$ are digits.

find $f(5)$ if $a_{1} > a_{2} > a_{3} > a_{4} > a_{5}$

**My Approach:**

I started of by assigning bounds to each $a_{i}$ but soon I realised that it would lead to too many sub cases and bashing. Could not think of any other approach.

Comment: I don't like how they first define $f$ and they later add an extra restriction to the digits. In any case, each subset of  $5$ elements of $\{0,1,\dots,9\}$ forces the values of the $a_i$ since they are decreasing, so $f(5) = \binom{10}{5}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem! For any 5-digit integer with it's digits all unequal, there is exactly one permutation of its digits that satisfy this condition (why?). Hence, $f(5)$ is equal to the number of ways to choose the $5$ digits in the integer. Since there are $10$ digits to choose from, and $0$ is allowed (since it cannot be at the beginning by the decreasing condition), it is just $\binom{10}{5}=252$.